# Problems layering images using z-index in CSS

Tags: css, z-index

Hi just looking to see if anyone can help me out with a small problem.

I'm trying to layer images using the `z-index` in css but for some reason even though i have given the div that i want on top the higher index value the layer I want beneath keeps pushing it down or covering the layer I want on top:

```
#work-img {
    background: url(../images/blots2.png) no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    width: 960px;
    height: 601px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 610px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 6;
    display:block;
 }

 #work {
    background: url(../images/my-work.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width:337px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 35px;
    top: 660px;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 700;
    display:block;
 }
```

Not sure what im doing wrong so any input anyone can give me would be really great thanks!

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your css. I did a quick example here and worked fine using the same properties as you.

Aren't these divs inheriting some property of another element? You can see that using firebug.

Comment: Hey @BrunoBruck, this isn't really an answer. You'd be better off the comment on the question.

Comment: @thomasfedb sorry, I know, but I've just signed up, so I can't comment yet, was the only way.